# Dynamically change height of "div", based on content with preset "width" and "height"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a "div" with preset "width" and "height". I need to change the height of that "div" based on content. I was looking for some JavaScript but couldn't find appropriate for me.

Here is my simple example, which needs an improvement http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry313/1zr6Lhwa/

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example </p> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    h2 {
font:18px/30px Arial;
}   
#content {
width:200px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
background: yellow;
}
```

**EDIT:** Initially preset "width" and "height" are important and can't be changed

Comment: why dont you use `height: auto;`?

Comment: Is what you're setting the minimum expected size? or is the div supposed to become 0 height and width?

Comment: @Alex Initially preset "width" and "height" are important and can't be changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) instead of `height` so that the `<div>` expands accordingly.

```css
h2 {
    font:18px/30px Arial;
}
#content {
    width:200px;
    min-height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    
<h2>Text</h2>

    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Suppose I have three div's like above. and let's say data from one div is increased so as the div height would increase. And if I want to increase the height of another 2 adjacent div's according to first div's height even if it has fewer words to wrap. How can we achieve this scenario? can you please help me out

Comment: @PrasannaSasne https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ look at flex box method in this blog. CSS grid can also achieve this if this is about the core layout of your page instead of just some small elements

Comment: Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 6):

Just remove `height` from CSS. If you need a preset height, use `min-height` instead. What about that one:

```css
h2 {
  font: 18px/30px Arial;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Example Example</p>  
</div>   
<br>
<div class="content">
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example </p>  
</div>
```

Edit: if you want to keep the height of the container and show scrollable content, use `overflow: auto;`

```css
h2 {
  font: 18px/30px Arial;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Example Example</p>  
</div>   
<br>
<div class="content">
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Initially preset "width" and "height" are important and can't be changed

Comment: if you want to change its height dynamically write some js: "$('#content').css('height','auto');"

Comment: It can't be changed from the preset condition, but can be changed based on the content

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#content').height($('#content')[0].scrollHeight)
```

Comment: Amazing !! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use `height:auto` like this;

```css
#content {
    height : auto;
}
```

Comment: Initially preset "width" and "height" are important and can't be changed